# better way to repeat custom frequency whithin months with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I would like to generate a date range with a custom frequency in a month, and that would be repeated over several month.
For example what I would like to have with the 5, 10 and 25 of each month is:

```
2020-01-05
2020-01-10
2020-01-25
2020-02-05
2020-02-10
2020-02-25
2020-03-05
2020-03-10
2020-03-25
```

I managed to do it with:

```
df = pd.date_range("2020-01-01", "2020-03-31", freq='D')
df = df[[d in [5,10,25] for d in df.day]]
```

But just in case is there a better way to do it without generating the whole list with all days ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([(d + pd.DateOffset(days=i)).date() for d in pd.date_range("2020-01-01", "2020-03-31", freq='MS') for i in (4, 9, 24)])

print (df)
```

Output:

```
0  2020-01-05
1  2020-01-10
2  2020-01-25
3  2020-02-05
4  2020-02-10
5  2020-02-25
6  2020-03-05
7  2020-03-10
8  2020-03-25
```